# Pressing a button more than once

Tags: android

I am getting force close when a button is pressed more than once. I have a condition like if internet is connected then google maps will be shown .If internet is not connected then i have kept a ALERT BOX displaying to check our internet connection .So the problem lies here. If internet is not connected when the button is pressed ONCE the alertbox is displayed. But if clicked more than once it shows a FORCE CLOSE. I have placed the alertbox display in catch block..

```
   case R.id.geocode_button:   // Place name as selected by the user.

            placeName = placeText.getText().toString();
            clik=1;         
            placenametemp = placeName;
            System.out.println(""+placenametemp);

            String [] optionArray = new String[numberOptions];
            Geocoder gcoder = new Geocoder(this);

            try
            { 
                              ///// code to display google map 


            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            if(!dialogShown)
                {
                    dialogShown = true;
                    //Show your dialog

                new  
        AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(R.drawable.icon).setTitle(
                " Check your Internet  
        Connection!").setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,  
                     int which)
                    {
                        dialogShown = false;    
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();

                Log.e("Geocoder", "I/O Failure; is network    
                                                                available?",e);
            }
                          }
```

```
//The LOG cat details :
```

```
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238): I/O Failure; is network available?
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238): java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:166)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at com.journey.snoozer.Mapper.onClick(Mapper.java:93)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    12-10 18:31:09.506: E/Geocoder(238):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-10 18:31:10.277: E/ActivityThread(238): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
    12-10 18:31:10.296: E/ActivityThread(238): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
    12-10 18:31:10.426: E/ActivityThread(238): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
    12-10 18:31:11.626: I/MapActivity(238): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
    12-10 18:31:11.626: E/MapActivity(238): Couldn't get connection factory client
    12-10 18:31:11.926: D/dalvikvm(238): GC freed 3247 objects / 233880 bytes in 241ms
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238): Remote Image Exception
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:557)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViews(ViewGroup.java:2146)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:196)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at com.journey.snoozer.ShowTheMap.mapProgress(ShowTheMap.java:143)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at com.journey.snoozer.ShowTheMap$loadImageTask.doInBackground(ShowTheMap.java:197)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at com.journey.snoozer.ShowTheMap$loadImageTask.doInBackground(ShowTheMap.java:1)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    12-10 18:31:11.936: E/DEBUGTAG(238):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
    12-10 18:31:12.756: D/dalvikvm(238): GC freed 7692 objects / 597720 bytes in 68ms
    12-10 18:31:12.886: D/dalvikvm(238): GC freed 5342 objects / 404384 bytes in 62ms
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238): Activity com.journey.snoozer.Mapper has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44ea2bc8 that was originally added here
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.journey.snoozer.Mapper has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44ea2bc8 that was originally added here
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:227)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at com.journey.snoozer.Mapper.onClick(Mapper.java:141)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    12-10 18:31:13.296: E/WindowManager(238):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post your logcat error report also

Comment: This is not right way to check internet status.

Comment: Use This link for check internet connection > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available

Comment: try setting this to alertdialog http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)

Comment: @Nadosh i have used alert dialog to display the message

Comment: some lines are missing from your logcat

Comment: i mean try setting this function to alertdialog setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)

Comment: How about dialog.cancel(); in onClick() ?

Comment: please post full logcat printout. There should be a line there saying that there was some exception and that exception was caused by something.

Comment: @Qw4z1 I have edited the log cat.. pls find the update.

Comment: please post full activity code if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can not show the alert dialog more than one time so put a check like this

first create a class level variable

```
public boolean dialogShown = false;
```

then  in here `case R.id.geocode_button`

```
if(!dialogShown){
dialogShown = true;
//Show your dialog
}
```

then in your dialog `ok` button click `listener`

```
dialogShown = false;
```

**Update**

check your internet connection like this

```
 void boolean checkInternet(){
  NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (i == null)
    return false;
  if (!i.isConnected())
    return false;
  if (!i.isAvailable())
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my catch block..Sir i guess the problem is not because of alert box coz  just tried the same with Toast msg and i am still getting force close when the button is pressed many times

Comment: Test it by putting this line in try block  `Geocoder gcoder = new Geocoder(this);`

Comment: also catch  this exception also  `catch (Exception e)`

Comment: sir the problem is not in the catch block ..i have removed everything inside catch block ..Wen the button is clicked many times it shows force close

Comment: You need to first check the internet connection before doing any processing but before that check the dialog shown status at the first line of your click event. then perform your rest of processing.

Answer (score 0):

Right. So first of all, that's not the way to check if internet connection is available. But that is not the problem here. 
The first problem is the CalledFromTheWrongThread exception, wich means that somewhere you are trying to access UI elements from another thread. Don't ever do that. I'm guessing you have an AsyncTask trying to post some update in a way that is not allowed.  (at com.journey.snoozer.ShowTheMap.mapProgress(ShowTheMap.java:143))

The main issue here though is the WindowLeaked exception a few lines down. That happens when you, for example, exit an activity and then try to access a Dialog. (Orientation changes etc.) Since you had the other exception with an AsyncTask involved I wonder if you cancel the first AsycTask when the IO exception occurs.

So make sure you use .cancel() on the AsyncTask in onPause() and dissmiss() on the dialog that the task creates.